# C# .NET WinForms. Visual studio won't recognise namespaces in subfolders

Tags: c#, .net, class, namespaces, projects-and-solutions

When I create a new folder, in this case `Model`, as a subfolder to the solution directory, and add a class in there, which is wrapped in a namespace, the namespace cannot be found.

Yes, I have tried both adding a `using` directive, and referring to the class directly, like `Model.Class`, from the main source file.

What is going on? In the class explorer, the `Model` folder is not visible, while it is visible in the solution explorer, it is visible. The other subfolders are visible in the class explorer.

Comment: Is it in the same project?
And if not, is your class possibly marked as internal?

Comment: It should be, but how do I check what is in a particular project. I've tried looking for the "add to project" option somewhere, but that is missing now as well.

Comment: The class is `public`. However, I think the problem is that the surrounding namespace is not even recognised. I find the fact that this particular folder is not being recognised by the class explorer quite suspicious. All other subfolders are shown there.

Comment: Is your class is actually in a project ?  I find it slightly strange that your class is under the solution folder directly and not under the project folder.

Comment: Aha, that seems to be the problem. The `Model` folder is not part of the project. I had to open it up in a text editor and have a look at the XML to see this. Forgive the stupid question, but how can I fix this?

Comment: Right click on a project, then "add existing item".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the namespace in the class file?

If you have a class file in the `Model.Class` folder, but the namespace in the file is `Model`, you still have to use `using Model;`

Comment: The `Model` folder (a subfolder of the solution dir) contains a source file `Class.cs`. In this source file, there is a namespace defined called `Model`. As i have mentioned, the `using Model` is useless, it doesn't even recognise it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The folder and code files in question were not part of the VS project.